# How to overwrite a plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need to add only one line of code to this plugin. I have been reading several practices but unfortunately I did not get them to work. Can that line be added without modifying the plugin files? Thank you very much!

```
    <?php 

// Porto Widget Woo Top Rated Products
add_shortcode( 'porto_widget_woo_top_rated_products', 'porto_shortcode_widget_woo_top_rated_products' );
add_action( 'vc_after_init', 'porto_load_widget_woo_top_rated_products_shortcode' );

function porto_shortcode_widget_woo_top_rated_products( $atts, $content = null ) {
    // $atts['title'] = 'Productos mejor valorados'; ----// line to add
    ob_start();
    if ( $template = porto_shortcode_woo_template( 'porto_widget_woo_top_rated_products' ) ) {
        include $template;
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}

?>
```

Comment: If the plugin provides action/filter hooks then, use the hooks from your theme or from another plugin to override the plugin. Otherwise, being under the plugin license, you have to clone the plugin, rename it into your own, and then do your changes.

Comment: thank you for your answer Mayeenul Islam.

Unfortunately the plugin has no hooks. How can I clone the plugin? any tutorial or site where I can fix? thank you very much!!

Comment: If the license permits you, you can download the WordPress Plugin and can change its name (to disable automatic updates) and can change code however you want.